# how to get the right solution with Nerdamer.js

Tags: javascript

I am using Nerdamer.js and it works fine with the code, but when I am solving some equations, the result i get is a function instead of just numbers
here is an example: 
**1x³+2x²+3x-4=0** 
if you solve this equation you will get these values: 
**0.7760454350285384** 
**1.7965885235495673** 
**-1.7965885235495673** 
or sometimes just the first value

but when i try to solve it with Nerdamer, I will an array of 3 objects with some informations, and the answers in each object are:

1. `(-1/3)*(-146+6*sqrt(606))^(1/3)*2^(-1/3)+(5/3)*(-146+6*sqrt(606))^(-1/3)*2^(1/3)-2/3`
2. `(1/6)*((-146+6*sqrt(606))^(1/3)*2^(-1/3))^(-1)*(-5+5*i*sqrt(3))+(1/6)*(-146+6*sqrt(606))^(1/3)*(1+i*sqrt(3))*2^(-1/3)-2/3`
3. `(1/6)*((-146+6*sqrt(606))^(1/3)*2^(-1/3))^(-1)*(-5-5*i*sqrt(3))+(1/6)*(-146+6*sqrt(606))^(1/3)*(-i*sqrt(3)+1)*2^(-1/3)-2/3`

and here is my code:

```
let nerdamer = require('nerdamer');
require('nerdamer/Algebra.js');
require('nerdamer/Calculus.js');
require('nerdamer/Solve.js');
```

and this is how i get the values:

```
var sol = nerdamer.solveEquations('1x^3+2x^2+3x-4=0');
console.log(sol[0].toString());
console.log(sol[1].toString());
console.log(sol[2].toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`.evaluate()`](https://nerdamer.com/functions/Expression.evaluate.html) for each solution.

```js
var sol = nerdamer
  .solveEquations('1x^3+2x^2+3x-4=0')
  .map(solution => nerdamer(solution).evaluate().text())
```

Comment: thank you so much, it is worked, I used evaluate before without putting them in nerdamer function, thank you for your help :)